# Finding the last digit of $323^{4097}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

"What is the last digit of the number $323^{4097}$? Explain."

I have tried to use either Fermat's little theorem (although I am not sure this is suitable) and the Euclidean algorithm but I keep getting stuck each time.

If anyone knows how to proceed and would be so kind to tell me, I would be very grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: Work mod 10 and note that $3^4$ ends in 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks to calculate:
$$ 323^{4097} \pmod{10} $$

By Euler's Totient Formula, for coprime $a,n$:
$$ a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n} $$

So we see that:
$$ \phi(10) = \phi(2 \cdot 5) = \phi(2)\phi(5) = 1 \cdot 4 = 4 $$
So:
\begin{align*}
323^{4097} &\equiv 3^{4096 + 1} \pmod{10} \\ 
&\equiv (3^4)^{1024} \cdot 3 \pmod{10} \\
&\equiv 3
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Note that $$323^{4097} \equiv 3^{4097} \pmod{10}$$

Also, observe the following:
$$3^1 \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$$

$$3^2 \equiv 9  \pmod{10}$$

$$3^3 \equiv 27 \equiv 7   \pmod{10}$$

$$3^4 \equiv 1  \pmod{10}$$

Comment: And $$4097\equiv1\pmod4$$

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can attack this problem by the following,

```
323^4097=323×323×3232.....
```

Therefore, the last digit has to be the last digit of some power of three, 
Where, 
3^1=3
3^2=9
3^3=27
3^4=81
3^5=243
.
.
In mod10 we have the pattern, 
3,9,7,1,3,9,7,1.....

Hence, the last digit of 323^4097 must be 3. Since 4097/4= 1024 with r=1

Answer (score 0):

Question ask
(323)^4097mod10
So
      (323)^1mod10=3
       Also observe 
       (3)¹mod10=3
       (3)²mod10=9
        (3)³mod10=7
        (3)⁴mod10=1
Hence 
         (  (3)⁴)^1274)×3 mod10=3

Comment: I cannot parse this answer. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).